# Trying to get checkbox, select option values. Not adding the value to remove error

Tags: jquery, html, forms

I've been searching for solutions, but I can't figure out what could be wrong with my code. Each text input is correctly calculating with my accumulator variable, but my checkbox, and my drop down menus are not.

I can't hit submit until all errors == 0, but my last three which are the Accept(checkbox) and both drop downs(State and Product) are not getting counted by the accumulator. In console they come out true but also(as an array), but they are not getting counted, because my error message still shows them. Any Help?

```
<form action="#" method="post" name="order" id="order">
<fieldset>
<legend>Personal Information</legend>
<ul>
  <li><label for="firstname">First Name:</label>
  <input type="text" maxlength="20" id="first"><span class="1"></span></li>
  <li><label for="lastname">Last Name:</label>
  <input type="text" maxlength="20" id="last"><span class="2"></span></li>
  <li><label for="address">Address:</label>
  <input type="text" maxlength="40" id="address"><span class="3"></span>
</li>
<li><label for="city">City:</label>
<input type="text" maxlength="30" id="city"><span class="4"></span></li>
<li><label for="state">State:</label>
<select name="states" id="states">
<option value="selectstate">--Select a State--</option>
<option value="WA">Washington</option>
<option value="OR">Oregon</option>
<option value="MT">Montana</option>
<option value="CA">California</option>
<option value="ID">Idaho</option>
</select><span class="5"></span></li>
<li><label for="product" id="product">Product:</label>
<select name="products" id="products">
<option value="selectproduct">--Select a Product--</option>
<option value="OR">Watch</option>
<option value="MT">Hats</option>
<option value="CA">Sunglasses</option>
<option value="ID">Shoes</option>
<option value="ID">Jewelry</option>
</select><span class="6"></span></li>
<li><label for="quantity">Quantity:</label>
<input type="text" maxlength="5" id="quantity"><span class="7"></span></li>
<li><label for="contact">Can we contact you by phone?</label>
<input type="radio" name="contactansweryes" value="Yes" checked>Yes
<input type="radio" name="contactanswerno" value="No">No <span class="8">
</span></li>
<li><label for="terms">Have you read the Terms and Conditions?</label>
<input type="checkbox" name="termsanswer[]" id="termsanswer" 
value="accept">I 
Accept <span class="9"></span>
<li><input type="submit" value="Submit"></li>
</ul>
</fieldset>
</form>
```

jQuery

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
    // selects the first text input
    $(':text:first').focus();
    // Values of each input
    firstVal = $('#first:text');
    lastVal = $('#last:text');
    addressVal = $('#address:text');
    cityVal = $('#city:text');
    stateVal = $('#states option:selected');
    productVal = $('#products option:selected');
    quantityVal = $('#quantity:text');
    contactVal = $(':radio:checked');
    termsVal = $('#termsanswer:checked');

    // console.log(stateVal[0], productVal[0]);

    $('#order').submit(function(evt) {
    var error = 0;
    $('#blankfields').text("");
    if ($(firstVal).val() == "") {
      $('#blankfields').append('<li>Please fill out first name!</li>');
      error++;
    }
    if ($(lastVal).val() == "") {
      $('#blankfields').append('<li>Please fill out last name!</li>');
            error++;
    }
    if ($(addressVal).val() == "") {
      $('#blankfields').append("<li>Please fill out address</li>");
            error++;
    }
    if ($(cityVal).val() == "") {
      $('#blankfields').append("<li>Please enter in City</li>");
            error++;
    }
    if ($(stateVal).text() == '--Select a State--') {
      $('#blankfields').append("<li>Please select a State</li>");
            error++;
            console.log(stateVal)
    }
    if ($(productVal).text() == '--Select a Product--') {
      $('#blankfields').append("<li>Please select a Product</li>");
            error++;
    }
    if ($(quantityVal).val() == "") {
      $('#blankfields').append("<li>Please select a Quantity</li>");
            error++;
    }
    if ($(contactVal).length == 0) {
      $('#blankfields').append("<li>Please select Yes or No to Contact</li>");
            error++;
    }
    if ($(termsVal).length == 0) {
      $('#blankfields').append("<li>Please check Accept</li>");
            error++;
    }
    console.log(error);
    if (error === 0) {
      return true;
    } else {
    return false;
    }
    }); // end of submit
    }); // end document ready
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to validate your radios,select,checkbox in submit event instead of `ready()` and use name grouping for radio element like

```
<input type="radio" name="contactanswer" value="Yes" checked>Yes
<input type="radio" name="contactanswer" value="No">No <span class="8">
```

And in JS use like,

```
 contactVal = $('[name="contactanswer"]:checked');
```

Snippet,

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  // selects the first text input
  $(':text:first').focus();
  // Values of each input
  firstVal = $('#first:text');
  lastVal = $('#last:text');
  addressVal = $('#address:text');
  cityVal = $('#city:text');
  stateVal = $('#states');
  productVal = $('#products');
  quantityVal = $('#quantity:text');


  // console.log(stateVal[0], productVal[0]);

  $('#order').submit(function(evt) {
    contactVal = $('[name="contactanswer"]:checked');
    termsVal = $('#termsanswer:checked');
    var error = 0;
    $('#blankfields').text("");
    if ($(firstVal).val() == "") {
      $('#blankfields').append('<li>Please fill out first name!</li>');
      error++;
    }
    if ($(lastVal).val() == "") {
      $('#blankfields').append('<li>Please fill out last name!</li>');
      error++;
    }
    if ($(addressVal).val() == "") {
      $('#blankfields').append("<li>Please fill out address</li>");
      error++;
    }
    if ($(cityVal).val() == "") {
      $('#blankfields').append("<li>Please enter in City</li>");
      error++;
    }
    if ($(stateVal).val() == 'selectstate') {
      $('#blankfields').append("<li>Please select a State</li>");
      error++;
    }
    if ($(productVal).val() == 'selectproduct') {
      $('#blankfields').append("<li>Please select a Product</li>");
      error++;
    }
    if ($(quantityVal).val() == "") {
      $('#blankfields').append("<li>Please select a Quantity</li>");
      error++;
    }
    if ($(contactVal).length == 0) {
      $('#blankfields').append("<li>Please select Yes or No to Contact</li>");
      error++;
    }
    if ($(termsVal).length == 0) {
      $('#blankfields').append("<li>Please check Accept</li>");
      error++;
    }
    console.log(error);
    if (error === 0) {
      return true;
    } else {
      return false;
    }
  }); // end of submit
}); // end document ready
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form action="#" method="post" name="order" id="order">
  <fieldset>
    <legend>Personal Information</legend>
    <ul>
      <li><label for="firstname">First Name:</label>
        <input type="text" maxlength="20" id="first"><span class="1"></span></li>
      <li><label for="lastname">Last Name:</label>
        <input type="text" maxlength="20" id="last"><span class="2"></span></li>
      <li><label for="address">Address:</label>
        <input type="text" maxlength="40" id="address"><span class="3"></span>
      </li>
      <li><label for="city">City:</label>
        <input type="text" maxlength="30" id="city"><span class="4"></span></li>
      <li><label for="state">State:</label>
        <select name="states" id="states">
<option value="selectstate">--Select a State--</option>
<option value="WA">Washington</option>
<option value="OR">Oregon</option>
<option value="MT">Montana</option>
<option value="CA">California</option>
<option value="ID">Idaho</option>
</select><span class="5"></span></li>
      <li><label for="product" id="product">Product:</label>
        <select name="products" id="products">
<option value="selectproduct">--Select a Product--</option>
<option value="OR">Watch</option>
<option value="MT">Hats</option>
<option value="CA">Sunglasses</option>
<option value="ID">Shoes</option>
<option value="ID">Jewelry</option>
</select><span class="6"></span></li>
      <li><label for="quantity">Quantity:</label>
        <input type="text" maxlength="5" id="quantity"><span class="7"></span></li>
      <li><label for="contact">Can we contact you by phone?</label>
        <input type="radio" name="contactanswer" value="Yes" checked>Yes
        <input type="radio" name="contactanswer" value="No">No <span class="8">
</span></li>
      <li><label for="terms">Have you read the Terms and Conditions?</label>
        <input type="checkbox" name="termsanswer[]" id="termsanswer" value="accept">I Accept <span class="9"></span>
        <li><input type="submit" value="Submit"></li>
    </ul>
  </fieldset>
</form>
<div id="blankfields"></div>
```

Comment: Oh boy did you save me from hours of searching through my code thank you so much! I didn't even think about that!!

Comment: Welcome @Allison.:)